# Traefik - Timeout during redirection to HTTPS to internal ressource

Tags: redirect, https, traefik

I’m stuck since 2 days on trying to get working the redirection (HTTPS).

I would like to access via my URL (and redirect to HTTPS) to an internal URL using duckdns.
However, i see that the redirect works but i got a timeout after a while, certainly during reaching the internal ressource.
Here is my toml’s, someone can help me ?

The ressource is ok when i use the URL in my LAN.

Here is the code :

```
# Global configuration
logLevel = "DEBUG"
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

#Log
 [traefikLog]
   filePath = "/etc/traefik/traefik.log"
 [accessLog]
 filePath = "/etc/traefik/access.log"

 # Entrypoints configuration
 [entryPoints]
   [entryPoints.http]
   address = ":80"
     [entryPoints.http.redirect]
     entryPoint = "https"
      [entryPoints.https]
      address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]

  # Let's Encrypt support
   [acme]
   email = "xxxxx"
   storage = "/etc/traefik/letsencrypt.json"
   #caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
   entryPoint = "https"
   onHostRule = true
   onDemand = false

   [acme.dnsChallenge]
   provider = "duckdns"
   delayBeforeCheck = 0

   [[acme.domains]]
   main = « xxxx.duckdns.org"

   # Rules configs
   [file]
   watch = true
   filename = "/etc/traefik/rules.toml"

   # Enable API and dashboard
   [api]
   dashboard = true
```

And here the rules.toml :

```
[backends]
    [backends.backend1]
    [backends.backend1.servers]
    [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
     url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:3000"
     weight = 1

 [frontends]
   [frontends.frontend1]
   entryPoints = ["https", "http"]
   backend = "backend1"
   passHostHeader = true
   [frontends.frontend1.routes]
     [frontends.frontend1.routes.route1]
     rule = "Host:xxx.duckdns.org"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like traefik times out while trying to reach `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:3000`. You need to fix that. Apart from that would be helpful to know how you run traefik, any logs and exact error message.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
When i try only HTTP, it works. It's when i want to redirect to HTTPS that i got the timeout.
Traefik is started in a docker container on a raspberry (a) and i want to reach an internal URL to an other raspberry (b) (in my LAN) which is a docker container also but i don't want to open the socket/TCP, only getting via URL.
I have not any errors in the log.

Comment: Well you are still not telling how you started traefik. You are not telling the exact error message. May be you did not expose required ports or something.. hard to tell with complete information you are not giving. Ideally, it should be a minimal reproducible example - that the easiest way to help you.

Comment: The traefik container used the open port 80:80 433:433 8080:8080 and i add 4000:4000 (but not required i guess) and use bridge network.
I have a timeout when i go to the url, redirect to 433 and trying to reach the internal URL. So http://DuckDns => (automatic redirect by traefik) https://DuckDns => want to reach backend but timeout in browser. However if i don't use redirect to HTTPS it works.

Comment: Hello, I finally found the solution. It was related to the letsencrypt key generated. Btw, i have used nginx for it.